# what do caret and percent sign mean in doxygen function documentation for .NET

Tags: .net, doxygen

I have the following function definition from documentation created with Doxygen for .NET code.

```
void GetCapacity  ( [Out] array< uint32_t >^%  channelCapacity,  
  [Out] array< uint32_t >^%  syncCapacity  
 )
```

What do the '^' and '%' mean?